# Is it possible to run moonbeam/Astar as a standalone network

Tags: frontier, evm, moonbeam, astar, acala

I am exploring moonbeam and astar projects. I would like to know if it is possible to run a standalone network without collators or relaychain.

I am interested in running a standalone network of one of them for my research project.
Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. In this case, your network will have to run (and use) its own `finality` gadget (rather than that of the relay chain). You can implement the `GRANDPA` pallet in your network for block finality.

Using `POA` shouldn't be an issue, since Substrate ships with `Aura`, which is a POA-based consensus engine.

[This guide](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/consensus-models/create-a-hybrid-node/) explains how you can customize the consensus engine of your chain. You can also check out [this guide](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/convert-a-solo-chain/) to get a high-level explanation of what's involved when converting from a Parachain to a solo chain.

Comment: Thanks for your question I am not asking about theoretical information but about how to practically do it

Answer (score 1):

To run an Astar local node you have two options:

[astar-local](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar) is the the closest to live networks - and have a block time of 2 sec. To run it follow these [instructions](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar#building-from-source) and run the node with (it will run a non-persistent local instance):

```
./target/release/astar-collator --dev --tmp
```

There is also [swanky-node](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/swanky-node) an local environment that targets WASM development (EVM is not available in this node). You can run it the same way as astar-local

If you need to run a local network with relay-chain + parachains to use XCM you will have to use [polkadot-launch](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-launch) but I guess this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for these info. I am looking to run a network (unconnected to relaychain like in shibuya) not a single dev node.

Comment: But Shibuya is connected to a (test) relay chain. You want to run your own standalone test-net ?

Comment: If yes then you should follow the answer by Abdulbee

Comment: I guess you are both right. I thought Shibuya was a standalone network (that was mentioned in an old documentary) but it seems it has its own relay chain